# How do I pay French taxes if I'm leaving the country before receiving the tax form?

Tags: france, taxes

I worked from April 2013 until now (March 2014) in France, but now I am moving abroad (to Italy). How can I pay my French taxes on revenue for 2013? What about 2014?

I have not declared anywhere in France to where I am moving, so I don't believe they can send me the tax form abroad.

Comment: If you register in Italy as having moved from France, Italy might inform France.

Comment: Well, I would be glad if Italy did that and France would sent the form directly to my house in Italy. But I'm not sure that will happen and I don't want to leave this pending...

Comment: In the UK you [must inform your local council](https://www.gov.uk/moving-or-retiring-abroad). I'm sure there must be a similar process in France.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that from the perspective of the French tax office, any form they send you is a convenience, you are still legally responsible for submitting all required information on your own. Since there is no general registration system in France, the best is to contact the tax office directly and give them your new address as soon as you have one:

> Afin de recevoir votre déclaration à votre adresse à l'étranger, n'oubliez pas de l'en informer.

Source: [Moving abroad](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F137.xhtml) on service-public.fr. There is also a link to a form you can use to report your income for the year in which you left France.

It might also be possible to report your income online or to get more info from the “[Service des impôts des particuliers non-résidents](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/R122.xhtml)”.

Finally, there is a [useful service on service-public.fr](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/R11193.xhtml) that can be used to inform the tax office, big utilities, the social security/pension/welfare organizations and the department in charge of motor vehicles of you new address all at once but unfortunately, it's only available if you are moving *within France*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have a hard time understanding more formal French, but I think all the info I need is there.

Comment: I confirm that in France, failing to pay your taxes is your fault unless you can prove that the tax office gave you incorrect advice. For example, if your tax papers get lots in the mail, it's your fault. I think it's now possible to declare all taxes online, but you still need to receive an enrollment number by snail mail.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get your mail forwarded from France to Italy for 6 month. Or at least you could 10 years ago. Would this cover at least the 2013 "déclaration de revenus"? You have to go to the post office to set this up.

As far as declaring your move, if you're self-employed you have to go to URSAFF to declare you're terminating your activities in France. If you are working for a company, you don't have anything to do.

Comment: thanks as well. I think 6 months will be fine to cover my 2013 declaration de revenus, as I should receive in May or June (by then, I`ll be in Italy already). FYI, I was working for a company in France.